# PHP OOP, MYSQLi Query

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have created a class named "Connection" for DB queries:

```
class Connection{
 public $mysqli;

 public function read($query){  
  $result= $this->mysqli->query($query);

  $num_result=$result->num_rows;

  if($num_result>0){
   while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()){

    $this->data[]=$rows;
  }          
   return $this->data;
  }
 }
}
```

This is how I'm calling my class:

```
$obj=new Connection("localhost","root","","testpaginate");

$query="SELECT * FROM paginate";
$result=$obj->read($query);
mysqli_free_result($result);

$queries="SELECT * FROM paginate where id=1";
$results=$obj->read($queries);
print_r($results);
?>
```

When I execute

```
$query="SELECT * FROM paginate";
$result=$obj->read($query);
```

it shows the right answer.

When I again execute

```
$queries="SELECT * FROM paginate where id=1";
$results=$obj->read($queries);
```

it shows current result with previous result

Why so? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: because you reuse `$this->data[]` and append your data there. just set `$this->data = array();` before you fill it;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good practice to declare variables correct in your classes.

You should do this every time you use them (if not used for other purposes):

```
class Foo {
    private $data;

    public function read()
    {
        $this->data = array();

        //do your stuff here, i.e. in your loop
        while(...)
           $this->data[] = $row;

        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

There could also be the possibility where you don't want to have a private variable associated:

```
class Foo {

    public function read()
    {
        $data = array();

        //do your stuff here, i.e. in your loop
        while(...)
           $data[] = $row;

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Now `$data` is just a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're appending to `$this->data` every time you call `read`. You need to reinitialise the array `$this->data` in the method:

```
if($num_result>0){
    $this->data = array();
    while($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $this->data[]=$rows;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you should not use the [] after $this->data. It means it will add rows to the array.

Comment: Sorry, but that's wrong, now the property will contain only the last row of the query.